# Impedances of a RC circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, impedance

[image]I am working on the question in the image attached. As shown, I have gotten the first question right, although with a bit of trial and error. I was able to solve circuit one on my own, but from there on.

For example:

In circuit two, I found that the impedance is: 1/jwC +R.
For w=0, the size of the impedance I think is R, = 10000 ohms, (substituting w=0 into the overall impedance equation I just wrote.) However, the answer is actually infinity, and I do not understand why this is.

I appreciate any help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to enlarge the picture... But it is more visible if you click on it...

Comment: 1/0 + R is not equal to R.

Comment: \$Z = \sqrt{(\frac{1}{0\cdot C})^2 + R^2} = \infty\$ Also, how can you have a negative capacitance?

Answer (score 0):

If w is 0, then jwC will be 0. The reciprocal of 0 is ±inf.

Comment: In the context of complex numbers, \$\pm \infty\$ is not all the possible infinities.